# Работа с Captcha

Tags: php, html

http://ideone.com/993ZNV

```
<form action="" method="post">
<img src="./?<?php echo session_name()?>=<?php echo session_id()?>">
<input type="text" name="keystring">
<input type="submit" value="Check">
</form>
<?php
if(count($_POST)>0) {
if(isset($_SESSION['captcha_keystring']) && $_SESSION['captcha_keystring'] === $_POST['keystring']){
echo "Верно";
}else{
echo "Ошибка°";
}
}
unset($_SESSION['captcha_keystring']);
?>
```

Можно ли сделать, чтобы, если "Верно", то чтобы оставалась только надпись "Верно", а остальное (Изображение, форма, кнопка) исчезало?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону параметра формы target (в нем указывается, куда будет загружаться ответ формы).